# "There is no question in the world whose answer cannot be found in Torah"

Tags: sources-mekorot, torah-study

Rabbi Yitzchak of Volozhin says, *"There is no question in the world whose answer cannot be found in Torah."*

Does anyone know where the source for Rabbi Yitzchak of Volozhin's statement can be found?

Comment: Apparently, it can be found in the Torah.

Comment: How do you know RYoV said this that we should look for its source?

Comment: Mr. Chiddushei Torah, many of your questions have suffered from the same shortcoming - you seem to have some source that you are searching for, which you somehow know exists, and you do not provide information about how you know that such a thing exists. There is nothing illegal about these questions, but they are not very constructive. Could you try to provide more context for your questions in the future?

Comment: See also [Ask].

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what R' Yiṣḥaq had in mind when he said that, but I'm guessing it has something to do with the end of the 5th chapter of of Avoth where we find: בן בג בג אומר הפוך בה והפוך בה דכולה בה

Comment: Hey, [I wanted to answer that](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19488791#19488791)! :P ....welcome to Mi Yodeya, Ha'Ivri; I hope you enjoy your stay!

Comment: Interesting that R' Yitzchak's father, R' Chaim Volozhiner, explained that mishna as meaning that seemingly disparate parts of the Torah shed light on each other (e.g. a halacha about *sukka* might explain how to permit an *agunah*), and Torah is an internally complete resource for explaining any specific part of the Torah. (Later in *Avos*, R' Chaim also comments that, if someone need guidance in his life, he can always find that guidance from the Torah).

Comment: @Fred oh man now it's gonna kill me trying to think how to mattir an aguna with hilchos succah.....

Comment: @user6591 Heh, yup. See the original comment from R' Chaim Volozhiner [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14555&st=&pgnum=68): "כן התורה למשל מדין סוכה יכולים להוציא להתיר עגונה וכדומה".

Answer (score 0):

Not having seen the alleged quote from Rabbi Yitzchak of Volozhin, I would point to the following line from the [Zohar (Pinchas, 221a)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14250&st=&pgnum=54):

דלית לך מלה זעירא דלא תשכח לה באורייתא

[There is no small thing that you will not find in the Torah].