# Are all answers in the Torah?

Tags: torah-study

Are the answers to any question found in the Torah? Or are there some questions that the Torah doesn't address?

Comment: What about the claim "This claim cannot be proven true or false by the Torah"?

Comment: Closely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/52550, as well as http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/52553.

Comment: Seems like a fine question, but a duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52553/there-is-no-question-in-the-world-whose-answer-cannot-be-found-in-torah http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52550/everything-is-in-the-torah http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60002/does-the-torah-know-about-quantum-mechanics-and-dna-synthesis/60004#60004

Answer (score 2):

The Mishna says at the end of Avos:

"Delve into it [the Torah] and delve into it for everything is in it."

Comment: Note that there are different ways to interpret that mishna (e.g. in [this comment](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52553/there-is-no-question-in-the-world-whose-answer-cannot-be-found-in-torah#comment138259_52572)).